# How can I minify CSS/JS files using symfony/webpack-encore?

Tags: symfony, webpack, webpack-encore

I'm trying to minify CSS and JS files while using `symfony/webpack-encore`. However, I cannot find a clear answer for what I need to do. I used `createSharedEntry` for layouts but I need to put them into a single file eg minifying. What do I need to do? Does `webpack-encore` have a specific function for this or do I need to use additional plugins?

Comment: https://github.com/symfony/webpack-encore/blob/master/lib/plugins/optimize-css-assets.js

Comment: For me, webpack encore minifies my files automatically when using the `build` command which creates a production build. It does not when I use the `dev` or `watch` commands since those are development build. Can you confirm you have the same behavior? Also, what version of webpack encore are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Symfony webpack encore is a bundle that helps you to read `entrypoint.js` generated by webpack. Nothing more. To minify js/css you need to learn more about Javascript/Webpack. There are a lot of tutorials and articles about it.
You could start from [this course](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/webpack-encore)